# Android Studio regularly stops supporting code highlighting and Hot Key support

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently upgraded Android Studio to this version

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 8192M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

Since this upgrade, Android Studio constantly stops working correctly...

In as much as it stops code highlighting, code suggestions, compile errors, pretty much everything that makes it a useful IDE stops working.

The only actions I can take to repair this useless state is to either Close and reopen Android Studio or Invalidate Cache and restart Android Studio.

Is there any configuration settings I ned to change/set?

Is there anything I can do to resolve these issues?

This unexpected/unwanted behaviour is having an adverse effect on my teams productivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to increase heap size.
   Go to Preferences (Mac Os)/File (Windows) -> Appearence & Behaviour -> Memory Setting.
2. Check if multiDex is enabled in Gradle
   android {
   .....
   defaultConfig {
   ............
   multiDexEnabled true
   }
   }
3. This helped me when I got stuck with the same problem using Android Arctic Fox: I  installed Android Bumblebee preview beta and problem disappeared.